# Histogram with x-axis in unequal steps

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I created a histogram with Python in Power BI and I am looking for a way to create the x-axis in steps.

My current Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(dataset.deviation_in_percent, bins=80, edgecolor="#6A9662",color="#DDFFDD")
plt.show()
```

Instead of `bins=80` I am looking for following:

For the column deviation_in_percent I would like to start the x-axis at -150% to -100% (create an interval). Then go on in 2.5% steps like -100% to -97.5%, -97.5% to -95.0% and so on until 100%. Then finish with 100% to 150%. Should be 82 intervalls at the end if i calculated it correctly.

Just to be sure for the y-axis: I suppose that i get the unique number of deviation_in_percent (or in other words the number of rows and not the distinct number of rows) right?

I am expecting a histogram like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving a number of bins, you can also give a list (or array) of bin edges.  `np.concatenate()` can help to concatenate different lists:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some random test data
data = np.random.randn(500, 4).cumsum(axis=0).ravel() * 3
# concatenate the bin edges
bin_edges = np.concatenate([[-150], np.linspace(-100, 100, 81), [150]])
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
plt.hist(data, bins=bin_edges, edgecolor="#6A9662", color="#DDFFDD")
plt.xlabel('deviation in percent')
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib histogram with unequal bins]

Comment: Hi JohanC. Many thanks! That looks easy and works. I get the info that "Duplicate rows are removed from the data". Is there a way in Python to avoid that and count each row? Or maybe i have to add a primary key in the power bi values field and Python will count over deviation_in_percent and primary key?

Comment: Maybe `plt.hist(dataset.reset_index()['deviation_in_percent'], bins=..., ...)` works to ignore the index? Or `plt.hist(dataset.deviation_in_percent.to_numpy(), bins=..., ...)`?

Comment: Hi @JohanC. Sorry for the late answer. How would it look like in the above code plt.hist(data, bins...)?

Comment: Did you mean `plt.hist(dataset.reset_index()['deviation_in_percent'], bins=bin_edges, edgecolor="#6A9662", color="#DDFFDD")`?